# C# removes backslash '\' from a string

Tags: c#

I am creating a PDF file on a windows temporary directory with this method:

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

and also I'm concatenating a the string with a DateTime like this code:

```
string pathPdf = string.Format(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "detalle-{0}{1:yyyyMMddhhmmss}.pdf", txtFolio_detalle_consum.Text, DateTime.Now);
```

this is the value of the string:

```
C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\detalle-6020121112102343.pdf
```

But when I try to use the value  later in the code some how c# removes me the doubel backslash ending the string in the following way:

```
C:UsersAdminAppDataLocalTempdetalle-6020121112102343.pdf
```

without the backslashes.

Any one have an Idea of why c# is doing this?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I output the variables with a Javascript alert using the following function:

```
protected void alerta(string msj)
{
    string script1 = @"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" + msj + "');</script>";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Adv", script1, false);
}
```

I'm also passing this variable to use it on a query string like this:

```
string scriptjs = string.Format("<script language='JavaScript'>window.open('emergentes_consum/vista_previa_imprimir.aspx?DocumentUrl={0}', '_blank', 'fullscreen=no')</script>",pathPdf);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Capturar_Emails", scriptjs, false);
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code sample to go with this. Likely just the string processing but hard to say without seeing code

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx

Comment: Where are you seeing the version without the backslashes?

Answer (score 3):

Launch the debugger, add the variable to your Watch window and go step by step through your program to find the code that removes these slashes. C# does not do that by itself.

Side note - use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to concatenate paths (folders and files).

As it turned out in the comments, the string in question was passed to JavaScript alert - so the solution was to add a call to [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx)

Comment: +1 for using `Path.Combine` - it handles all of the slashes for you, which means you don't have to try to remember what ends in a slash and what doesn't

Comment: Is very strange because I use the debugger with a watch, but when I output the variable there is no more backslashes.
I will try Path.Combine and let you know.

Comment: how do you output the value? Maybe it is a problem with displaying the value - try to ouput `value.Replace("\\", "_")` to see if the underscores get displayed.

Comment: @Knaģis I used Replace and it replaced the "\\" characters for "_" so then I tried: `pathPdf.Replace("\\","\\")` and "\\" dissapeared. I don't know how this is happening, but is giving me a headache.

Comment: how are you outputting the variable? Console.Write, debugger window or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm outputting  the variable on an Javascript alert, and also putting on a query string, I will update the questiong with the code Im using to output.

Comment: voila - Use HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx

Comment: @Knaģis HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode did the trick, It encoded my string and now is working, thanks a lot for your help, this Thread can be close o mark a solved.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the value of the string.
That's how the debugger displays the string.

If you write a string literal in source code, you need to escape the `\`s, or use a verbatim string literal (`@"C:\a\b"`)